# VB.NET - reference to an object under construction is not valid when calling another constructor

Tags: vb.net

Is there any difference between doing this:

```
Public Class Class1
    Protected Test1 As String
    Public Sub New(ByVal test2 As String)
        Test1 = test2
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Class2
    Inherits Class1

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("called from class 2")
    End Sub

End Class
```

and this:

```
Public Class Class1
    Protected Test1 As String
End Class

Public Class Class2
    Inherits Class1

    Public Sub New()
        Test1 = "Called from class 2"
    End Sub
End Class
```

In the first example, the superclass instance variable is initialised in the constructor.  In the second example, the superclass instance variable is initialised in the subclass.

The reason I ask is because I am trying to do this from the subclass:

```
Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New(                   System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Item("PurgeFile" & Me.GetType.Name), & _
               System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Item("PurgeHeader" & Me.GetType.Name) )
        End Sub
```

and I am getting an error: "reference to an object under construction is not valid when calling another constructor".

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `Me` within `MyBase.New()` call, so following part of your code is invalid:

```
Me.GetType.Name
```

**Update**

There is huge difference your 2 samples: First one doesn't allow `Class1` initialization without constructor parameter and the second one does.

I would rather think about something like:

```
Public MustInherit Class Class1
    Public MustOverride ReadOnly Property Test1 As String
End Class

Public Class Class2
    Inherits Class1

    Private _Test1 As String = "Called from class 2"

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Test1 As String
        Get
            Return _Test1
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

[Reference from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tsft9yh(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way around this? My second code fragment perhaps.

Comment: @Westie He can't do it before calling base class constructor. w0051977: I don't think there is a workaround.

Comment: You can't access properties within `MyBase` constructor call either, unless they are `Shared` (`static` in C#)

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, is there anything wrong conceptually with the second code fragment i.e. the superclass variable is initialised in the subclass rather than the constructor?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, could you answer the question in my last comment.  I will then be in a position to mark your answer green.

Comment: Check out my answer again. Updated with a little hint.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, I was trying to say that if every class that inherits from class1 initialises the Test1 variable in the constructor then there is no problem.  I think your READ ONLY property solution is cleaner though.  Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, I agree for that simple sample. However you should look at the bigger picture too.

Comment: I think what your saying is that you should not assume that another developer will know to initialise Test1 in zero arguement constructor.  Using a READ ONLY attribute is clearer.+1.